# Simplifying a trigonometric sum

Tags: simplifying-expressions, trigonometry

I want to caculate `Cos[θ] + Cos[2 θ]+ ... + Cos[n θ]`

```
Sum[Cos[k θ], {k, 1, n}]
```

> ```
> Cos[1/2 (1 + n) θ] Csc[θ/2] Sin[(n θ)/2]
> ```

But when I use Euler's formula

```
Re[Expand[ExpToTrig[Sum[E^(I k θ), {k, 1, n}]]]]
```

I get

> ```
>  Im[Sin[θ]/(-1 + Cos[θ] + I Sin[θ])] - 
>  Im[(Cos[n θ] Sin[θ])/(-1 + Cos[θ] + I Sin[θ])] - 
>  Im[(Cos[θ] Sin[n θ])/(-1 + Cos[θ] + I Sin[θ])] + 
>  Re[-(Cos[θ]/(-1 + Cos[θ] + I Sin[θ])) + 
>    (Cos[θ] Cos[n θ])/(-1 + Cos[θ] + I Sin[θ]) - 
>    (Sin[θ] Sin[n θ])/(-1 + Cos[θ] + I Sin[θ])]
> ```

Why doesn't *Mathmatica* simplify it?

Comment: I'm sorry, this is completely random, but I didn't want to start another question and it appears there is no way to contact users here directly.
I was wondering if you could please tell me how you copy-pasted your code so it looks so nice.

Answer (score 5):

The rule of thumb that I use is this: Put `Re` as close as possible to the expression that I want to obtain its real (or imaginary) part and then put the result inside `ComplexExpand` and not `Expand`. (same applied to `Im`).

`ComplexExpand` assumes variables in expression are all real, and hence can do more simplification than `Expand`.

So the pattern is  `Simplify[ ComplexExpand [ Re [ .... ] ] ]`

Compare the following 3 cases, all using the same expression to start with:

```
exp = ExpToTrig[Sum[E^(I k \[Theta]), {k, 1, n}]]
```

[image]

### Case 1, Re outside, ComplexExpand inside

```
 Simplify@Re@ComplexExpand@exp
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

### Case 2, Re inside, Expand outside

```
 Simplify@Expand@Re@exp
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

### Case 3, Re inside,  ComplexExpand outside

```
 Simplify@ComplexExpand@Re@exp
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: I like your answer, but where did the `x y^2` come from? Did you have some uncleared variable assignments?

Comment: @m_goldberg I was doing my HW's in the other side :(, must have sneeked in without my noticing. Will fix now